# Java EE : Do not submit if the datepicker is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a dynamic table (the data are extracted from a database). For each line, I have a datepicker which allows the user to select a date than click on the submit button (to submit the value of the datepicker).
I don't want that the submit button works if the datepicker is empty or if it's not filled with a specific format 'dd/mm/yy'.
Can you help me please?
Here is my code :

```
$(function() {
   jQuery('.date-pick').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
   });
});
```

Comment: Which datepicker plugin of the many available ones are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should try a [form validator plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Here is a [built-in date validation method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date).